# Centroid projection in MySQL Spatial

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns a set of geometries associated to my entities of interest. This query is used to build a KML to display in Google Maps.

The column I retrieve is of type `GEOMETRY` and, within my dataset, mostly contains a `GeometryCollection` with only a single element of type `Polygon`. Other records are of `MultiPolygon` type.

I would like to calculate the centroid for all the geometries in the resultset, just like the `AVG` operator behaves. I mean, given a query like `SELECT GEOMETRY FROM GEOENTITIES WHERE [..]` I would like MySQL to compute the union of geometries of all rows in the resultset and then compute their centroid.

As an example, let's pick Italian cities. If my result set contains only a polygon in Rome and a polygon in Milan, I expect the centroid of both being around Florence.

Actually, the `UNION()` function works on a column-based level and not on a row level. You can unite two geometries from two columns within the same row (as per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-that-create-new-geometries-from-existing-ones.html#function_union))

I need an aggregation operator to unite polygons through all rows into a collection, from which I might expect to compute the centroid.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think current mysql (5.7 VERSION) including such spatial functions (maybe in the future)
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions-that-create-new-geometries-from-existing-ones.html#functions-that-produce-new-geometries)

There is line: OpenGIS proposes a number of other functions that can produce geometries. They are designed to implement spatial operators. These functions are **not implemented** in MySQL.

Therefore, since you can't do it in the MySQL, the only way to make it happen is on the application side, whatever you are using.
For instance, OpenLayer javascript can do this: (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19964/how-to-merge-two-polygons-in-openlayers)

Or, you can use an spatial-oriented database, such as http://postgis.net/, or Oracle Spatial :)